# Clang and llc with --x86-asm-syntax=intel produce AT&T syntax

Tags: clang, llvm

Below are two command line strings I used to output to assembly language listing using --x86-asm-syntax=intel.  Both command line strings work, but they both produce AT&T syntax, not Intel syntax.

```
sudo clang-8 -S -mllvm --x86-asm-syntax=intel Svx.c

sudo llc-8 --x86-asm-syntax=intel Svx.ll -o Svx.s
```

at the top of each file it says:

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
```

But the code it produces is AT&T syntax.

I've researched and haven't found an answer.

Thanks for any ideas on why these command strings do not produce Intel syntax.

Comment: Hmm.  Works for me (on [Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/m4PajW)) using v8.0.  Have you tried just using `-masm=intel`?  Also, does anything interesting happen between where you see `.intel_syntax` and the first lines that contain the at&t formatted code?  Any inline asm's for example?  What's your first at&t formatted instruction?  And it might be worth checking the timestamp on the output file to make sure it's freshly generated from the current command line.  It happens.

Comment: Thanks @David Wohlferd -- it works for me on Godbolt, too.  I went to Godbolt because that strips out the cfi directives and gives me only Intel syntax.  But even with -masm=intel I get the cfi directives, which I don't want.

Comment: I'm confused.  Is the problem "at&t syntax?"  Or just .cfi directives (which aren't specific to at&t)?  If the goal is to make the output look like godbolt's "Filter all assembler directives from the output," I'd think a grep script could do this.  You couldn't just look for `.` at the beginning of a line (that would exclude things like `.quad`), so you might need to have an exclusion file.  Maybe you could contact Matt directly and ask him how he does this.

Comment: Well, the goal was to get all Intel syntax without the cfi directives.  I don't want cfi directives in the code because it doesn't compile correctly.  So far, only Godbolt's explorer gave me exactly what I am looking for.  I'll try the grep script and see.

Comment: Perhaps you could check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38552509/2189500) answer.  It contains a link to the godbolt github.